# Есть ДатаСет , " Чёрная Пятница " с kaggle в нём замаскированны данные о товаре, нужно их расшифровать

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, numpy

Я решил попрактиковаться в анализе данных и взял dataset с kaggle "Black Friday".
Там есть 2 важных показателя  это категории и название продукта , но они зашифрованы. Я не могу правильно вытащить из dataset ссылки, когда я сохраняю их в .txt файл то они сохраняются в сокращённом формате, как в анаконде их выводит:

```
0        https://www.amazon.com/Sanus-VLF410B1-10-Inch-...
1        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
2        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
3        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
4        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
5        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
6        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
7        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
8        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
9        http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
10       http://reviews.bestbuy.com/3545/4784804/review...
```

Как правильно вытащить данные из dataset, без сокращений и чтобы они были по порядку?

Вот первые наброски парсира:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/3.0.195.27 Safari/532.0'}

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Acer-Predator-i7-8750H-GeForce-Keyboard/dp/B07PLK8C6P/ref=sr_1_1?fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1564684133&refinements=p_89%3AAcer&rnid=2528832011&s=computers-intl-ship&sr=1-1'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


def get_name(url):
    data = []
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    data = soup.find(id='titleSection').text.strip()

    return data

product_name = []

product_name.append(get_name(url))
tr = ''.join(product_name)
print(tr)
```

Без добавления в dataset названия и фильтрации по магазинам.

Как я пытался сохранить данные из переменной:

```
text1 = df.sourceURLs[0:]
text = open('test.txt', 'w')
text.write(str(text1))
text.close()
```

Comment: что значит `чтобы они были по порядку`?

Comment: Шёл в таком же порядке как в DataSete в основном , для того чтоб потом можно было добавить в основной сет новую переменную , названия продукта

Comment: а где та часть кода где вы читаете датасет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas обрезает данные только при выводе на печать. Если обрабатывать данные или сохранять их в файл, используя методы Pandas, то ничего обрезано не будет.

Для того чтобы контролировать параметры вывода/обрезания данных на экран, в Pandas существует метод [pd.set_option(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html):

> Available options:
>
> - compute.[use_bottleneck, use_numexpr]
> - display.[chop_threshold, colheader_justify, column_space, date_dayfirst, date_yearfirst, encoding, expand_frame_repr,
>     float_format]
> - display.html.[border, table_schema, use_mathjax]
> - display.[large_repr]
> - display.latex.[escape, longtable, multicolumn, multicolumn_format, multirow, repr]
> - display.[max_categories, max_columns, max_colwidth, max_info_columns, max_info_rows, max_rows, max_seq_items,
>     memory_usage, min_rows, multi_sparse, notebook_repr_html,
>     pprint_nest_depth, precision, show_dimensions]
> - display.unicode.[ambiguous_as_wide, east_asian_width]
> - display.[width]
> - io.excel.ods.[reader]
> - io.excel.xls.[reader, writer]
> - io.excel.xlsm.[reader, writer]
> - io.excel.xlsx.[reader, writer]
> - io.hdf.[default_format, dropna_table]
> - io.parquet.[engine]
> - mode.[chained_assignment, sim_interactive, use_inf_as_na, use_inf_as_null]
> - plotting.[backend]
> - plotting.matplotlib.[register_converters]

---

чтобы сохранить один столбец DataFrame в качестве текстового файла:

```
df["sourceURLs"].to_csv(r"c:/temp/urls.txt", index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('DatafinitiElectronicsProductsPricingData.csv')
df.head(10).T
df.sourceURLs
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развернутые ответы.

Comment: для того чтобы дополнить / отредактировать вопрос, воспользуйтесь кнопкой ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1009703/edit) под вопросом